# JPA spring boot many to many mapping i tried to fetch project by user id but not receive data in assign user

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
data class Project(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  val id: Long? = null,
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
  @JoinTable(
    name = "project_user",
    joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = true, updatable = true, referencedColumnName = "id")],
    inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true, updatable = true, referencedColumnName = "id")]
  )
  // @JsonIgnoreProperties("projects")
  //  @JsonManagedReference
  var assignUser: MutableSet<Users>? = null,
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Component
data class Users(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  val id: Long? = null,
  val firstname: String? = null,
  val lastname: String? = null,
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assignUser", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
  //@JsonBackReference
  //@JsonIgnoreProperties("assignUser")
  val projects: MutableSet<Project>? = null,
)
```

i tried both but none of working

@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM p.assignUser u WHERE u.id = :userId)")
fun findProjectsByUserId(userId: Long): List

fun findProjectsByAssignUser_Id(userId: Long): List

not sure issue is related to my code or many to many mapping

mapping table is created succesfully

Answer (score 0):

Based on your entity definitions, the correct naming should be:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM p.assignUser u WHERE u.id = :userId)")
fun findProjectsByUserId(userId: Long): List<Project>
```

Make sure that you have a repository interface for your Project entity that extends `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository`.

For example:

```
@Repository
interface ProjectRepository : JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
    fun findProjectsByAssignUser_Id(userId: Long): List<Project>

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM p.assignUser u WHERE u.id = :userId)")
    fun findProjectsByUserId(userId: Long): List<Project>
}
```

Make sure that you have properly annotated the `Project` and `Users` classes with `@Entity` and `@Table`, and the `ProjectRepository` is a Spring `@Repository` been so that Spring Data JPA can handle the queries properly

Comment: Hi, @nebil Thanks for solution this is not working
i used this version of spring boot  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"